# jQuery - get all divs inside a div with class ".container"

Tags: jquery, dom

**Scenario:**

I got a menu containing links:

```
Main Menu Item
--------------
Sub: Show Grid > SubSub: <a>Show #first</a>
                         <a>Show #second</a>
                         <a>Show #third</a>
```

Now i need to find all divs with an css `#ID`  who are first level DOM elements inside the `.container` div. These elements should get appended to "Sub: Show Grid" and add a class via a click on it.

```
<!-- The mark up -->
<div class="container">
    <div id="first">1st</div>
    <div id="second">2nd</div>
    <div id="third">3rd</div>
</div>
```

**Question:**

- How would i find the first level div with an (undefined/not known) `#ID` with jQuery?
- How can i interact with the result in php - will I get an array as result to build the SubSub menu out of it?

---

**Edit #1**

To make it more clear what I'm trying to do - In pseudo code:

```
$divs_received_from_jquery_fn = 'how do I get the divs (IDs?) as array(?) and interact with them in the following code?';
foreach ( $divs_received_from_jquery_fn as $div )
{
    add_menu_item( array( 
         'parent' => 'Sub: Show Grid'
        ,'name'   => 'Show #'.$div
        ,'href'   => ''
        ,'meta'   => array( 
                        'onclick' => 'jQuery(".container #".$div).toggleClass("showgrid");'
         ) 
    ) );
}
```

**Edit #2**

The "real world" example. The output is an onclick event for an a-link. My problem is that i want to call the function `foreach` for every `div[id]` below the `.container` div and simply don't know how to interact properly with javascript & php.

```
?>
<script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery(".container > div[id]").each(function(){
        var context = $(this);
        <?php 
        // SHOWGRID - parts
        // @since v0.3
        $wp_admin_bar->add_menu( // trigger the function via the global $wp_admin_bar var that calls the class
            array(
                 'parent'   => 'showgrid' // parent menu item
                ,'id'       => 'showgrid - ' + this.id // menu item ID
                ,'title'    => sprintf( // menu item label
                     __( '%1$s show grid parts %2$s%3$s', OXO_TEXTDOMAIN )
                    ,'<span style="background: none;">'
                    ,'<span class="showgridparts-on hide">&#x2714;</span>'
                    ,'<span class="showgridparts-off">&times;</span>' 
                 )
                ,'href'     => '' // stays empty to not trigger anything
                ,'meta'     => array( // HERE GOES THE ACTUAL jQuery FUNCTION
                    'onclick'   => 'jQuery("#" + this.id).toggleClass("showgrid"); jQuery(".showgridparts-on").toggleClass("hide"); jQuery(".showgridparts-off").toggleClass("hide"); return false;'
                 )
            ) 
        );
        ?>
    });
</script>
<?php
```

Answer (score 71, accepted):

### Known ID

```
$(".container > #first");
```

or

```
$(".container").children("#first");
```

or since IDs should be unique within a single document:

```
$("#first");
```

**The last one is of course the fastest.**

### Unknown ID

Since you're saying that you don't know their ID top couple of the upper selectors (where `#first` is written), can be changed to:

```
$(".container > div");
$(".container").children("div");
```

The last one (of the first three selectors) that only uses ID is of course not possible to be changed in this way.

If you also need to filter out only those child `DIV` elements that define ID attribute you'd write selectors down this way:

```
$(".container > div[id]");
$(".container").children("div[id]");
```

### Attach click handler

Add the following code to attach click handler to any of your preferred selector:

```
// use selector of your choice and call 'click' on it
$(".container > div").click(function(){
    // if you need element's ID
    var divID = this.id;
    cache your element if you intend to use it multiple times
    var clickedDiv = $(this);
    // add CSS class to it
    clickedDiv.addClass("add-some-class");
    // do other stuff that needs to be done
});
```

### CSS3 Selectors specification

I would also like to point you to [CSS3 selector specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#selectors) that jQuery uses. It will help you lots in the future because there may be some selectors you're not aware of at all and could make your life much much easier.

### After your edited question

I'm not completey sure that I know what you're after even though you've written some pseudo code... Anyway. Some parts can still be answered:

```
$(".container > div[id]").each(function(){
    var context = $(this);
    // get menu parent element: Sub: Show Grid
    // maybe I'm not appending to the correct element here but you should know
    context.appendTo(context.parent().parent());
    context.text("Show #" + this.id);
    context.attr("href", "");
    context.click(function(evt){
        evt.preventDefault();
        $(this).toggleClass("showgrid");
    })
});
```

the last thee `context` usages could be combined into a single chained one:

```
context.text(...).attr(...).click(...);
```

### Regarding DOM elements

You can always get the underlaying DOM element from the jQuery result set.

```
$(...).get(0)
// or
$(...)[0]
```

will get you the first DOM element from the jQuery result set. jQuery result is always a set of elements even though there's none in them or only one.

But when I used `.each()` function and provided an anonymous function that will be called on each element in the set, `this` keyword actually refers to the DOM element.

```
$(...).each(function(){
    var DOMelement = this;
    var jQueryElement = $(this);
    ...
});
```

I hope this clears some things for your.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer +1. CSS3 is currently a no go for my situation. I extended/edited the Q to give you detail insights with a pseudo code example of what I'm trying to acchieve.

Comment: @kaiser: If you're using jQuery, CSS3 is something that it supports when writing selectors. They don't have to be supported by browser at all. jQuery will allow you to use them.

Comment: @Robert Koritnik - Thanks for the heads up. Didn't know. Can I somehow interact with the fetched DOM elements (the divs below .container that got an ID)?

Comment: @keiser: Check my edited answer. And regarding your question about DOM elements. Yes you can always get the pure DOM element from the jQuery set. Check my additional info in the answer.

Comment: @Robert Koritnik - Thanks for the update. My problem is writing a function that switches between javascript and php. I update/edit my question with the real world example to make it more clear.

Comment: @keiser: Javascript nad PHP don't have much to do with each other. Javascript executes on the client, PHP on the server. Unless you're posting some data back at server, your server side PHP will be completely unaware of the processes that happen on the client. Maybe you think that you can execute some things on the server, then send the rest to the client, do some processing there and then continue on the server. That's not hoe it goes. Or at least not out of the box. A lot can be achieved but the more complex scenario you'll think of the more knowledge you'll need.

Comment: @Robert Koritnik: That exactly the problem i was facing (server side vs. DOM related). I now got i running after a lot of trial'n'error, but your explanation helped alot getting around it. Thank you very very very very much, mate!

Comment: @kaiser: I'm glad things started working for you. You're welcome

Comment: How do I fix my issue? It seems the contents first line is shown and anything else is hidden... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25126615/how-to-display-all-the-divs-inside-a-parent-div

Answer (score 3):

To get all divs under 'container', use the following:

```
$(".container>div")  //or
$(".container").children("div");
```

You can stipulate a specific `#id` instead of `div` to get a particular one.

You say you want a div with an 'undefined' id. if I understand you right, the following would achieve this:

```
$(".container>div[id=]")
```

Comment: +1 - I updated the Q with a pseudo code example to show where my problem with interacting with the jQuery result is.

Answer (score 1):

To set the class when clicking on a div immediately within the .container element, you could use:

```
<script>
$('.container>div').click(function () {
        $(this).addClass('whatever')
    });
</script>
```

Comment: +1 - I updated the Q with a pseudo code example to show where my problem with interacting with the jQuery result is.

Answer (score 1):

From http://api.jquery.com/jQuery/

> Selector Context
>   By default, selectors perform their searches within the DOM starting at the document root. However, an alternate context can be given for the search by using the optional second parameter to the $() function. For example, to do a search within an event handler, the search can be restricted like so:

```
$( "div.foo" ).click(function() { 
   $( "span", this ).addClass( "bar" );
});
```

> When the search for the span selector is restricted to the context of this, only spans within the clicked element will get the additional class.

So for your example I would suggest something like:

```
$("div", ".container").each(function(){
     //do whatever
 });
```