# How to display ALL the divs inside a parent DIV

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, html, asp.net

I have the following code which is my `Default.aspx`:

```
<div style="padding-left: 10px; padding-top: 10px;">
    <asp:BulletedList ID="tabs" ClientIDMode="Static" runat="server" DisplayMode="HyperLink">
        <asp:ListItem Text="Status" Value="#tab1"></asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem Text="Your Tasks" Value="#tab2"></asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem Text="Messages" Value="#tab3"></asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem Text="Dependencies" Value="#tab4"></asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem Text="Documents" Value="#tab5"></asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem Text="Pro-Forma" Value="#tab6"></asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem Text="Admin Controls" Value="#tab7"></asp:ListItem>
    </asp:BulletedList>

    <asp:Panel ID="content" runat="server" ClientIDMode="Static">
        <asp:Panel ID="tab1" ClientIDMode="Static" runat="server">THIS IS A TEST #1
            <asp:GridView ID="yourTasksGV" runat="server" ClientIDMode="Static" EmptyDataText="There is no data to display">
            </asp:GridView>
        </asp:Panel>
        <asp:Panel ID="tab2" ClientIDMode="Static" runat="server">THIS IS A TEST #2
        </asp:Panel>
        <asp:Panel ID="tab3" ClientIDMode="Static" runat="server">THIS IS A TEST #3</asp:Panel>
        <asp:Panel ID="tab4" ClientIDMode="Static" runat="server">THIS IS A TEST #4</asp:Panel>
        <asp:Panel ID="tab5" ClientIDMode="Static" runat="server">THIS IS A TEST #5</asp:Panel>
        <asp:Panel ID="tab6" ClientIDMode="Static" runat="server">THIS IS A TEST #6</asp:Panel>
        <asp:Panel ID="tab7" ClientIDMode="Static" runat="server">THIS IS A TEST #7</asp:Panel>
    </asp:Panel>
</div>
```

The `tabs` and `contents` are controlled by JQuery:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#content div").hide(); // Initially hide all content
        $("#tabs li:first").attr("id", "current"); // Activate first tab
        $("#content div:first").fadeIn(); // Show first tab content

        $('#tabs a').click(function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            $("#content div").hide(); //Hide all content
            $("#tabs li").attr("id", ""); //Reset id's
            $(this).parent().attr("id", "current"); // Activate this
            //$('#' + $(this).attr('title')).fadeIn(); // Show content for current tab
            $($(this).attr('href')).fadeIn();
        });
    });
</script>
```

I am populating the `GridView` from code behind during `Page_Load`. The `THIS IS A TEST #1` is displayed but the `GridView` is not shown. When I go in to the `Developer Tools` I can see the Table which was generated but somehow it is wrapped within a DIV (`display: hidden`) which I am sure was created by the JQuery code above.

Here is what it looks like:

[image]

I am not sure why there is the DIV with the `6` is created from and where are there all those `JQuery###################` in those contents DIV?

How can I modify the JQuery so that when the page first loads, anything inside the first `content` DIV is shown (even if there are multiples) and then if I go to the other tabs and comes back to the first tab it is still displayed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You only want the children hidden , not all descendent `<div>`

Try:

```
$("#content").children().hide();
```

And you can chain your show() to it also

```
$("#content").children().hide().first().show();
```

Answer (score 3):

```
$("#content div").hide()
```

Hides the following:

```
<div id="content">
   <div>
      <!-- will be hidden -->
      <div>
         <!-- will also be hidden -->
         <div>
         <!-- will also also be hidden -->
         ... and so on
         </div>
      </div>           
   </div>
</div>
```

You may want to assign a common class to all of your tab-level `<asp:Panel>` elements, and do something closer to

```
$('.myTabClass').hide();
```

Edit: alternatively, find out what is rendering a `<div>` around the gridview. Does it come by default with the gridview?

Comment: `$("#content div:first").fadeIn();` then displays the first div inside the content when the page loads.

Comment: Yes, but does it also fade in the `<div>` inside the first `<div>`? The reason Charlietfl's answer works is that .children() restricts it to hide only the first level of `<div>` down from the `#content`

Answer (score 1):

The reason is because you are hiding all of the child divs and then fading in the only the first child div.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {

        // HIDES ALL CHILD DIVS!!  EVEN GRANDCHILD DIVS
        $("#content div").hide(); // Initially hide all content
        $("#tabs li:first").attr("id", "current"); // Activate first tab

        // ONLY FIRST CHILD IS UNHIDDEN
        $("#content div:first").fadeIn(); // Show first tab content

        $('#tabs a').click(function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            $("#content div").hide(); //Hide all content
            $("#tabs li").attr("id", ""); //Reset id's
            $(this).parent().attr("id", "current"); // Activate this
            //$('#' + $(this).attr('title')).fadeIn(); // Show content for current tab
            $($(this).attr('href')).fadeIn();
        });
    });
</script>
```

a fix could be:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#content div[id^='tab']").hide(); // Initially hide all content
        $("#tabs li:first").attr("id", "current"); // Activate first tab
        $("#content div[id^='tab']:first").fadeIn(); // Show first tab content

        $('#tabs a').click(function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            $("#content div").hide(); //Hide all content
            $("#tabs li").attr("id", ""); //Reset id's
            $(this).parent().attr("id", "current"); // Activate this
            //$('#' + $(this).attr('title')).fadeIn(); // Show content for current tab
            $($(this).attr('href')).fadeIn();
        });
    });
</script>
```